# oracle external table load

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse

I have 100 records in players.dat file  like

```
 PIT   INDIANPOLISH  COLTS
```

and then new line same again.  How can I load this data into external table?

Here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TEAMS1( 
    TEAM_ID VARCHAR2(20) 
    , TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(35)
    ) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( 
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY DATA_WAREHOUSE
    ACCESS PARAMETERS ( 
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline 
        fields terminated by whitespace 
        missing fields values are null ( 
            TEAM_ID VARCHAR(20),
            TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(35) 
            TERMINATED BY '/N')
            ) 
    LOCATION ('NFL_Teams.dat')
) ;
```

Here is the error:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout 
ORA-29400: data cartridge error 
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters 
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "fields": expecting one of: "field" 
KUP-01007: at line 3 column 9 29913. 00000 - "error in executing %s callout"
```

Comment: No idea about SQL Server, but for Oracle you can read the documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

Comment: It is for oracle only . I have tried but it giving me access parameter error

Comment: You're getting an error.  You haven't told us what specific error you're getting.  You haven't shown us the code that you're using.  Without those things, I can't imagine how anyone would be able to answer you.  When you edit your question to include those things, you probably also want to include 4 or 5 lines of data from your .dat file, tell us what the format of the .dat file is (comma separated, tab separated, fixed width, etc.), tell us where the file is located, show us the definition of the Oracle directory that you created, etc.

Comment: CREATE TABLE TEAMS1(
TEAM_ID  VARCHAR2(20) , TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(35))
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY DATA_WAREHOUSE
ACCESS PARAMETERS 
( RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline 
fields terminated by whitespace 
missing fields values are null
 ( TEAM_ID VARCHAR(20),
 TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(35) TERMINATED BY '/N'))
 LOCATION ('NFL_Teams.dat'))
; this is my code and error is

Comment: ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "fields": expecting one of: "field"
KUP-01007: at line 3 column 9
29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"

Comment: Make sure the OS oracle user has read privileges for the directory defined in DATA_WAREHOUSE.

Comment: yes I have grant privileges to user already

Comment: The permissions are needed in both database and operative system level. Did you grant permissions to your DB user AND chmod the target directory to the OS user?

Comment: you should edit your question and include code from this comment there

Answer (score 1):

The error message points to a syntax problem, it even gives us a clue.

```
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "fields": expecting one of: "field"
```

Sure enough, your table definition has this ...

```
missing fields values are null
```

... when it should be this:

```
missing field values are null
```

---

You have a major problem with your data file.  Your table definition specifies `fields terminated by whitespace` but your sample data shows a team name consisting of two words,`INDIANPOLISH COLTS`.  You won't be able to load that.

The best solution is to get the providing system to do the right thing and supply a data file which uses a sensible field delimiter and/or field enclosure.    (If this is a school assignment you can do this yourself.)

A less desirable solution would be to pre-process the data file, using regex to delimit or enclose the fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, you can try to correct it according to this:

```
 CREATE TABLE TEAMS1( TEAM_CODE varchar2(10), TEAM_ID VARCHAR2(20) , TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(35)) ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY DATA_WAREHOUSE ACCESS PARAMETERS 
( RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline  fields ( TEAM_CODE varchar(10), TEAM_ID VARCHAR(20), 
TEAM_NAME VARCHAR(35) )) LOCATION ('players.dat')) ;
```

Then you can create standard table let's say TEAMS(team_id varchar2(20), team_name varchar2(35)) and load it from external table:

```
 insert into teams select team_id, team_name from teams1;
```